# Calculate sin(318°) knowing cos(42°) = 0.74

Tags: trigonometry

What would be the procedure to find a trigonometric function value in terms of the value of another trigonometric function (evaluated in some angle)?

Would appreciate any help

Comment: $318^\circ+42^\circ=360^\circ$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\sin 318^\circ = \sin(-42^\circ) = -\sin42^\circ$.

Use the identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x=1$.

Comment: Thank you both. So, now I have: $sin(-42°)^2 + cos(-42°)^2 = 1$

Comment: @F.Zer Yes, just express $\sin(-42^\circ)$ from there, knowing that it is negative (because $-42^\circ$ is in the fourth quadrant)

Comment: Great. You probably meant that -42° is in the fourth quadrant. Simplifying: $-sin(42°)= 0.672, sin(42°) = -0.672$. Something like that?

Comment: @F.Zer I did mean that $-42^\circ$ is in the fourth quadrant. But be careful that $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$ implies that either $\sin x = \sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}$ or $\sin x = -\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}$. But, since we know that $x=-42^\circ$ has a negative sine, we take the second option, i.e. $\sin (-42^\circ) = -0.672$.

Comment: Really appreciate that comment. I took the square root without taking that into account. Thank you.